# Mysql - get 6 results before and after the desired value to make comparison chart

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comparison, ranking

Today I am facing a challenge for me, that I could solve with multiple queries, a little bit of PHP and some other funny things, but I was wondering whether what I mean to do can be achieved with a single query and/or stored fn/procedure.

I explain myself better:
in a list of cities, I need to pick up a value (say "general expenses") of that named city (say "Rome").

Pretty simple.

What I would like to do is:
Have 6 records for the same value BEFORE and 6 AFTER the Rome one.
So I would see something:

```
| position | city      | expenses |
|    35    | Paris     | 1364775  |
|    36    | Milan     | 1378499  |
|    37    | New York  | 1385759  |
|    38    | London    | 1398594  |
|    39    | Oslo      | 1404648  |
|    40    | Munchen   | 1414857  |
|    41    | Rome      | 1425773  | ***  <--this is the value I need
|    42    | Dublin    | 1437588  |
|    43    | Athen     | 1447758  |
|    44    | Stockholm | 1458593  |
|    46    | Helsinki  | 1467489  |
|    47    | Moscow    | 1477484  |
|    48    | Kiev      | 1485665  |
```

These values will populate a bars chart.

As you can see there is also another complexity level: the position.

Position must be calculated on all the records.

So let's say I have 100 records, I will have the ranking position from 1 to 100, but only the "limited 13" records must be output.

Any link, suggestion, tutorial or else the could help me out with that?
Thank you in advance as always.

**EDIT** 
Position MUST BE calculated. It is not an input value.

Anyway, thanks folks for all your efforts.

Comment: is the position always continuous number?

Comment: position must be calculated. It is not an input value

Comment: how is the position calculated?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
all_ranked.*
FROM (select rank 
      from (SELECT a.id             AS id2,
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS Rank
            FROM the_table a
            JOIN
                (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                ORDER BY position DESC
            ) AS B) 
      where B.id=1234567) as rank_record, <--- just one record - value of rank
      (SELECT a.id             AS id2,
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS Rank
            FROM the_table a
            JOIN
                (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                ORDER BY position DESC
            ) AS all_ranked <--- all ranked users
where all_ranked.rank>=rank_record.rank-6 and all_ranked.rank>=rank_record.rank+6
```

Create 2 queries joined in one. The first gets position and the second sets positions and cut's desired fragment

Comment: thanks Stnislav. I receive an error on your query stating that each derived table must have its own alias. And the position is not an input, but a calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored function/procedure that takes in an input that indicates the subject record, e.g., "Rome" to derive a ranking, which I shall refer to here as the perceived ID (PID) for that record, e.g., 41. You can then use a variable @PID to store that location.

Then you can do your ranking query again but select all records.

```
SELECT .... WHERE Ranking BETWEEN (@PID-6) AND (@PID+6)
```

An advantage to doing it this way is that the function/procedure can take in an additional parameter to allow it to fetch X records after and Y records before that ranking. It would be easier to read and maintain as well.

Performing it as a single query without the use of PHP would be tricky as you need to insert a WHERE clause in which the condition is the result of another query.

Answer (score 0):

If your position is going to be continuous unique number you can use sub-query in where condition.

```
SELECT `position`, `city`, `expenses`
    FROM table_name
    WHERE `position` > (
      SELECT `position`-7
          FROM table_name
          WHERE `city`='Rome'
      )
    ORDER BY `position`
    LIMIT 13
```

PS: I am not an expert in SQL. There may be better more efficient ways.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this should work: You get the positions with a variable you increment while selecting in MySQL. Then you would have to select this "temporary table" twice; once to find Rome, once to find all 13 records:

```
select
from
(
  select  @rowno := @rowno + 1 as position, city, expenses
  from cities
  cross join (select @rowno := 0)
  order by expenses 
) 
where abs(position - 
  (
    select position, city
    from
    (
      select  @rowno := @rowno + 1 as position, city, expenses
      from cities
      cross join (select @rowno := 0)
      order by expenses 
    )
    where city = 'Rome'
  )
) <= 6;
```

Comment: thanks Thorsten. This is what i get: '1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `from ( select @rowno := @rowno + 1 as position, codice_alfanumerico_istat, ' at line 2`  where `codice_alfanumerico_istat` is the identifier for cities

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rank as position,city,expenses FROM
(SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position, city, expenses, FIND_IN_SET( position, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( position
ORDER BY position ASC ) 
FROM test )
) AS rank
FROM test,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
HAVING rank BETWEEN(SELECT  FIND_IN_SET( position, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( position
ORDER BY position ASC ) 
FROM test )
)-6 AS rank
FROM test
WHERE expenses=1425773)
AND
(SELECT  FIND_IN_SET( position, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( position
ORDER BY position ASC ) 
FROM test )
)+6 AS rank
FROM test
WHERE expenses=1425773))x
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c7a8/13)

Comment: thanks mihai, but position is not an input value. It must be calculated. Moreover, I cannot see Rome in your fiddle :)

Comment: @Aptivus Changed it,ignore position in the table.

Comment: Your query is cool, but on a bunch of 171 records, the +6/-6 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Aptivus Add them in the fiddle,i see it works and there are more than 12.Thank you for your cool adjective,it means a lot to me.

Comment: here is a [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a33c/1) with real data. No POSITION field is available in the table. I have tried to adapt your query, but with no success due to POSITION field. The **a01** field is the number of inhabitants, the **a05** is one kind of expense, the **a06** is another kind of expense. The field **codice_alfanumerico_istat** is the city identification code. The analysis must be done on **a05**

Comment: Wonderful Mihai! On the real data I experience some anomalous behaviours of your query, but I think I can try to figure out what is happening. Do you mind if I consider to give you feedback? Thanks.

Comment: @Aptivus Well try to recreate the issues in a fiddle,other than that cant help you much.

Comment: Please Mihai, have a look [**THIS SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a33c/13). As you can see, the rank is calculated correctly and it is not based on the id of the records. How I am supposed to restrict the range of results of that query, in order to have 6 values over and 6 under the record, say, with "codice_alfanumerico_istat" LIKE '032006'? I have tried to adapt your precious query, but with no success. I'm always getting "rank" values based on the id of the record. I'm getting insane about it :)